# Azure API management Policy Expressions

Tags: azure, policy, azure-api-management

Pretty new to this so in Azure API Management, I am trying to configure a policy to log api traffic to event hub.  I got most of it working except for some reason the response body always comes back empty when it is not.

Below is a slimmed down version, here is the syntax I am using:

```
var responseBody = "";
if (context.Response.Body != null)
        {
            responseBody = context.Response.Body.As<string>(preserveContent: true);
        }
return responseBody;
```

I have tested multiple APIs they all have a response body but none of these bodies were returned.

Any idea?

Comment: Where do you place this expression and log-to-eventhub policy? In what policy section?

Comment: yes in the policy section

Comment: Which? Inbound or outbound?

Comment: Do you still have the problem? One reason can be that, if you already pulled the Response.Body at another point before in the policy, it is empty.